# Getting error org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to filter feeds which contains user actvitity. I am using @QueryResult object to retrieve the result. I need both the feeds and the relationship information of user Liked Feeds. But while retrieving the feeds getting error: org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable. (I am using SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE and neo4j 2.1.7)

```
@QueryResult
public interface FeedsIterableResult {
        @ResultColumn("f")
        Collection<Feed> getFeeds();

        @ResultColumn("r")
        Collection<UserInspiredByFeed> getPaths();
    }

@Query("match (feed:Feed)-[:FEED_CONTAINS_TAG]->(t:Tag)<-[:USER_FAVORITED_TAG]-(u:User{username:{1}}) "
            + "where feed.feedType in {0} "
            + "with u, feed "
            + "optional match (u)-[rel:USER_LIKED_FEED]->(feed) "
            + "return feed as f, rel as r "
            + "union match (u:User{username:{1}})-[:USER_FAVORITED_USER]->(u2:User)-[:USER_LIKED_FEED|:USER_CREATED_FEED]->(feed:Feed) "
            + "where feed.feedType in {0} "
            + "with u2, feed "
            + "optional match (u2)-[rel:USER_LIKED_FEED]->(feed) "
            + "return feed as f, rel as r "         
            + "order by f.timeAdded desc "
            + "skip {2} limit {3}")
FeedsIterableResult getAllFavoriteFeeds(String[] typeFilter, String userName, int skip, int limit);
```

If I convert the query as suggested by Luanne, I am getting following error:
Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Collection.

New Query:

```
    @QueryResult
    public interface FeedsIterableResult {
        @ResultColumn("f")
        List<Feed> getFeeds();

        @ResultColumn("r")
        List<UserInspiredByFeed> getPaths();
    }

@Query("match (feed:Feed)-[:FEED_CONTAINS_TAG]->(t:Tag)<-[:USER_FAVORITED_TAG]-(u:User{username:{1}}) "
            + "where feed.feedType in {0} "
            + "with u, feed "
            + "optional match (u)-[rel:USER_INSPIREDBY_FEED]->(feed) "
            + "return collect(feed) as f, collect(rel) as r "
            + "union match (u:User{username:{1}})-[:USER_FAVORITED_USER]->(u2:User)-[:USER_INSPIREDBY_FEED|:USER_CREATED_FEED]->(feed:Feed) "
            + "where feed.feedType in {0} "
            + "with u2, feed "
            + "optional match (u2)-[rel:USER_INSPIREDBY_FEED]->(feed) "
            + "return collect(feed) as f, collect(rel) as r "           
            + "order by f.timeAdded desc "
            + "skip {2} limit {3}")
FeedsIterableResult getAllFavoriteFeeds(String[] typeFilter, String userName, int skip, int limit );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns `feed as f`, a node, and `rel as r`, a relationship. 
But the `FeedsIterableResult` expects them to be collections. Each "row" returned by that query will contain a `feed` node and a `rel` relationship.

To match your QueryResult, you would have to change your Cypher query to return collections of feeds and rels. Or change `FeedsIterableResult` to expect single nodes and relationships and have `getAllFavoriteFeeds` return a Collection of `FeedsIterableResult`.

Comment: But can i send collect(feed) and collect(rel) in union? I tried this too, but it was not working.

Comment: It should return two columns for feeds and relation respectively but right now giving exception.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause of your new exception, but the union will return two rows, one row from each union. But you're mapping onto a single FeedsIterableResult.

Comment: Its ok Luanne I have got the result using your other suggestion, by returning single nodes. But there is one minor problem in that too. The skip and limit I have applied is just working for the second union but I want it to work on whole result.

Comment: That's not possible currently. You can apply it to each part of the union but not the entire resultset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80660/discussion-between-anshul-goel-and-luanne).